# Extending array properties javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to extend the properties for all array with simple function (it's for my homework)

```
Array.prototype.remove=(function(value){
var i;
var cleanedArray = new Array();
for(i= 0;i<this.length;i++)
{
    if(value !== this[i])
    {
        cleanedArray.push(this[i]);
    }
}

 this.length = cleanedArray.length;
 for(i=0;i<this.length;i++)
 {
     this[i] = cleanedArray[i];
 } })();

 var simpleArray = new Array(3,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
 simpleArray.remove(1); console.log(simpleArray);
```

but i get an error in console, can somebody help me ?

error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'remove' of object [object Array] is not a function
```

Comment: Can you add the error to your question?

Comment: What is the error you get?? Pls put the output in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a function, you don't need those parenthesis and you don't need to call it.

You may declare it as

```
  Array.prototype.remove=function(value){ // <== no opening parenthesis before function
     var i;
     var cleanedArray = new Array();
     for(i= 0;i<this.length;i++) {
        if(value !== this[i])
        {
            cleanedArray.push(this[i]);
        }
     }
     this.length = cleanedArray.length;
     for(i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
         this[i] = cleanedArray[i];
     } 
  }; // <== simply the end of the function declaration
```

It looks like you were confused with [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) but you don't need that construct here.

If you want your function to be not enumerable, you may do it using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "remove", {
    enumerable: false, // not really necessary, that's implicitly false
    value: function(value) {
        var i;
         var cleanedArray = new Array();
         for(i= 0;i<this.length;i++) {
            if(value !== this[i])
            {
                cleanedArray.push(this[i]);
            }
         }
         this.length = cleanedArray.length;
         for(i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
             this[i] = cleanedArray[i];
         } 
    }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uvekem/2/edit)

Comment: thanks but now i got another problem the remove functions is doing its work great,but my array has new element which is _remove:function_

Comment: If you want your function (which is a property) to be not enumerable, you may use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). See edit.